# Applozic Android Custom UI Latest message list throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, customization, applozic

This is my logcat

[image]

When I try to get Latest message list for android Custom UI using this method I get error in image.

```
ApplozicConversation.getMessageList(context, isScroll, new MessageListHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(List<Message> messageList, ApplozicException e) {
            if(e == null){
            // do something
            }else{
            //Error in fetching messages. 
            e.printStrackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Comment: @jaymin Thank you for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I have solved this Using Custom Class.
for now I have added manual check in MessageListTask class in onPostExecute method.

this issue will there for a users who does not have any conversations i.e. 0 conversations in List.

Comment: Suggested by Applozic team.